# Background for starting measure theoretic probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, soft-question

Will studying (all of) Abbott's Understanding Analysis prepare me well enough for me to study Robert Ash's Probability and Measure Theory? Or will I need something more advanced like Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis?

Comment: Yes it will.  Intuitively though I think you can start the measure theory book without going through Abbott's.

Comment: Abbott is a book that provides a good (intuitive) view on the concepts of convergence of sequences and series, integration and differentiation. So it can be very helpful to read it.

Comment: I think you are well equipped. But if you want to get more insight in the probability part, you should know some basic probability. It will make you appreciate the constructions and how everything is generalized in a common set up.

Comment: Elementary Probability Theory of Kai Lai Chung is an excellent book about basic probability.

Comment: @BananaCatsCategoryTheoryApp Could you please comment on Robert Ash's Probability and Measure Theory's quality as an expository textbook?